# Integer Solutions to Cosine's Dot Product Formula

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Say one wanted to test their students on the dot product formula without a calculator. One would (being a nice teacher and all) natural like to pick numbers in the plane that are "nice" and satisfy a unit circle angle, i.e. find $i,j,k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$, such that $$<i,j><k,l>=|<i,j>||<k,l>|\cdot \cos(\theta),$$ where $\theta=30,45,60,120,135,150$. After writing a script to check almost all integers within about a 15 by 15 grid, it seems as though solutions only exist for $\theta=45,135$. Has anyone see this before and/or is there a general proof of this interesting fact?

For completeness sake, here are some solutions for $\theta=45$:

<1,1>, <1,-1>

<7,1>, <4,-3>

<14,7>, <1,3>

<14,7>, <3,-1>

For angles, $30,60$, I guess I will have to resort to radical coordinates? :-(

Comment: Or take three-dimensional vectors.

Comment: @HansLundmark Good point. With a third coordinate, integer solutions are much more promising, in fact we have the following, $$<0,4,4><2,4,2>=|<0,4,4>||<2,4,2>|\cos(30^\circ)$$ $$<0,4,4><4,2,4>=|<0,4,4>||<4,2,4>|\cos(45^\circ)$$ $$<1,1,4><4,1,1>=|<1,1,4>||<4,1,1>|\cos(60^\circ)$$ This makes the above problem even more intriguing. Why are there are lack of integer solutions for cosine's dot product formula in two dimensions?

Comment: Probably related (although I haven't thought very deeply about it): The defining conditions for a [root system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system) of vectors imply that the cosine of the angle between two vectors is constrained to be a half-integral multiple of a square root of an integer. And root systems can be classified; there aren't that many possibilities. (By the way, it looks much better if you use "\langle" and "\rangle" for angle brackets instead of "less/greater than".)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a right triangle with theta = 30, and the hypotenuse of length one. It should be easy to see the leg lengths using trig are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$
Thus we have an irrational value for tangent. The irrationals absorb elements of the rationals, so you will have difficulty making these work out to be integers.

On a slightly related note, are you familiar with Mathematics Educators SE? Though this question specifically probably does not fit as well there as it does here, something like "what is a good way to teach dot product without a calculator?" would probably get you god reception.

Added info:
Suppose we have two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$, v=(a,b) and w=(c,d). Then, v*w=|v|*|w|*$\cos{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them. Without loss of generality, we can think of $\theta$ as the angle of the triangle with points (0,0),(c-a,0),(c-a,d-b). 
Now that the above is stated for clarity, we want to say that $\theta$ is 30 (degrees) and that we want all of the points in the triangle to be in $\mathbb Z^2$.
We also know that the ratio between two of the sides in an irrational number.

So let's talk about this in generality. Suppose we have x,y,z where: $x \in \mathbb Q, y \in \mathbb R, \notin \mathbb Q$ and we want to know if it is possible for z to be in $\mathbb Q$ if the relation x*y=z is true. Since $x \in \mathbb Q$, $\exists a,b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\frac{a}{b}=x$. There also *cannot* be any c and d st $\frac{c}{d}=y$ because y is irrational.
We also know that x*y=z $\rightarrow\frac{a}{b}*y=z$ Since all of $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$ they are closed under multiplication (and $b \neq 0$ by assumption bc $x \in \mathbb Q$), we can then say that $y=\frac{z*b}{a}$.

Suppose that $z \in \mathbb Q$. Well, z,a,b are closed under addition, so $\frac{z*a}{b} \in \mathbb Q$, which is equal to y, which is not in $\mathbb Q$. That would make life awkward. Fortunately, we have the idea of set complements, so if $z$ can't be in $\mathbb Q$, then it has to be in "not Q" (where the universe is $\mathbb R$). That by definition is the irrationals.

The conclusion to draw from this is that the irrationals "absorb," elements from the rationals. Since in the dot product question you have some integers (also rational) related by multiplication by an irrational, you cannot get a rational (or integer) solution.

Hope this explains in enough detail to make it clear.

Comment: Seems as though you are saying, ``If tangent is irrational, then Cosine's dot product has no integer solutions''. Do you have proof of this? The proof is really the heart of what I am looking for.

Comment: I will edit that in.

Comment: I am really confused about your comments. In particular, you say that $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are vectors that form a triangle, that "without loss of generality" can be thought of as a triangle $(0,0)$, $(c-a,0)$, $(c-a,d-b)$. However, this first triangle outlined by the two vectors certainly need not be a right triangle, yet your reduced triangle is a right triangle.

Comment: I also have another issue, it seems you try to show that an "irrational times a rational must be  irrational", which is clearly false, since $$\sqrt{2}*0=0.$$

Comment: The non-zero is assumed as well due to the parameters of the problem. If you had that cos was 0 then the problem is already solved. I should have mentioned it, but I didn't want to post another edit immediately after the first (which is when I realized)